# IMessage on my iPad is not working

Tags: messages

I keep getting "unable to send message" when using the message app on my iPad Air.

I discovered that I could turn off the subject field and was able to send one message successfully.

Then I try to send another message, nothing happens when I click on the send button.

Answer (score 2):

there could be many issues that are preventing you from using imessage. This may help you fix that.

1.**check that your iMessage is still enabled in settings**[ go into settings, scroll down until you find iMessage then click it. Check if the button is green if not click it to turn it on.

[image: how to turn iMessage on]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot this first sign out of iMessage. Then follow this guide:

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201422

Once you're eliminated a server side issue or an activation issue, then pay attention to if you are using WiFi or Cellular Data when the next failure happens. You can follow the article above on carrier support or contacting Apple support to further determine why activation is failing or why sending fails when activation works.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, but none of these answers work for me. iMessage is not working on my laptop now as well as on the iPad, but I can send messages on my iPhone.